# what is wrong in this code (palindrome java)? can anyone suggest how to reduce its complexity

Tags: java

The following code is giving correct output as given on the codechef problem page: http://www.codechef.com/problems/LAPIN but getting wrong answer on submission please tell me the possible problem with my code

here is the question

> Lapindrome is defined as a string which when split in the middle,
>   gives two halves having the same characters and same frequency of each
>   character. If there are odd number of characters in the string, we
>   ignore the middle character and check for lapindrome. For example gaga
>   is a lapindrome, since the two halves ga and ga have the same
>   characters with same frequency. Also, abccab, rotor and xyzxy are a
>   few examples of lapindromes. Note that abbaab is NOT a lapindrome. The
>   two halves contain the same characters but their frequencies do not
>   match. Your task is simple. Given a string, you need to tell if it is
>   a lapindrome.

Input:

First line of input contains a single integer T, the number of test cases.

Each test is a single line containing a string S composed of only lowercase English alphabet.

Output:

For each test case, output on a separate line: "YES" if the string is a lapindrome and "NO" if it is not.

and here is the code

```
public class Lapindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<=t;i++)
        {
            String word= sc.nextLine();
            int wl= word.length();

            char[] carr= word.toCharArray();

            int fh=0;
            int lh=0;

            for(int st=0, end=wl-1 ; st<wl/2 && end>= wl/2; st++, end--) 
            {       
                fh+=carr[st];
                lh+=carr[end];  
            }

            if(fh!=0) 
            {
                if(fh==lh)System.out.println("YES");
                else System.out.println("NO");
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. to reduce complexity, it's like eating an elephant. How do you do that? -- step by step. Make methods. Have a method that takes as param a String and returns whether it is a lapindrome or not. Now you have separated out your logic of reading strings from system in and figuring out if things are a lapindrome. This makes your code more flexible, AND reduces complexity; you can then look at the method 'public boolean isLapindrome(String word)' on its own without having to read through the scanner bits, and the rule of 'if yues, then print YES', which has nothing to do with the task of figuring out if something is a lapindrome. In other words, have code that is concerned with reading input and writing output, and have another slice of code that is concerned with figuring out if things are lapindromes. The two should stick to their responsibilities.
2. The problem is that your code is taking a shortcut that it shouldn't. `carr[st]` contains the ASCII code of the letter at the 'st' position in the word. You then just add these. That causes 2 problems:

   1. For a sufficiently long word, an int doesn't cover what you need. ints cannot be larger than 2^31-1 (about 2 billion). I doubt this is the cause (you need quite a long string to go over), but it's a problem with this code.
   2. the ascii code of a, plus the ascii code of d is equal to the ascii code of b plus the ascii code of c. Both are equal to 197. So, your program says that 'adcb' is a lapindrome.

It's homework, so I think the point is that you figure out how to fix this. This plan of adding to a single number is never going to work. You have to think of something else.